Is the image of an affine variety under a regular and injective map a quasiprojective variety?
Original version
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb A^n$ be an irreducible closed subvariety, $\phi :\ X \to \mathbb A^m $ is a regular map that is injective. Then is the image $\phi(X)$ a quasiprojective variety?
Here a closed subvariety of $\mathbb A^n$ means that $X$ is the set of common roots of some polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_s\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$,where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.
While a regular map here is simply a polynomial map. A quasiprojective variety is the open subset of a closed subvariety, or equivalently, is of the form $X_1\backslash X_2$,where $X_i$ are closed subvarieties.
Simplified version
(I can provide details if needed about how to reduce the original question to this one)
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb A^{n+m}$ be an irreducible closed subvariety, and the map $$\phi:X\to \mathbb A^m,\ (x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)\longmapsto (y_1,\dots,y_m)$$
is injective. Then is $\phi(X)\subseteq \mathbb A^m$ a quasiprojective subvariety of $\mathbb A^m$?
Why injective?
Then why do I emphasize that the map $\phi$ is injective in the original and simplified version? Here is a counterexample if it's not injective:
Consider the following map :
$$\mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^2, (x,y)\longmapsto (x-y,x^2-y^2+1) ,$$
then this map is a regular map (but not injective). Its image is $D(x)\cup \{ (0,1) \}$, which is not a quasiprojective variety.
Algebraic version
Moreover, here is an algebraic version of this question (here we don't distinguish $k^n$ and $\mathbb A^n$):
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $f_1,\dots,f_s\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]$ where $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m$ are indeterminants. If for any given $(y_1,\dots,y_m)\in k^m$, the system of polynomial equations with $x_1,\dots,x_n$ being indeterminants:
$$\begin{cases}
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)=0\\
f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)=0\\
\dots\\
f_s(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)=0
\end{cases}$$
has at most one solution $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\in k^n$. Let $Y$ be the set of all those $(y_1,\dots,y_m)\in k^m$ such that the corresponding system has exactly one solution, then is $Y$ a quasiprojective variety of $k^m$?
Guess
I have a guess that I think may be helpful for the algebraic version, that is , under the conditions in the algebraic version, can we solve all the $x_i$ as a rational function in $y_1,\dots,y_m$ from the system of equations? Here by rational function I mean the quotient of two polynomials.
I have tried to search for similar questions on this website but I didn't find any. I would be very happy if anyone could help me or discuss this interesting question along with me!

I think it is possibly confusing to speak of "quasiprojective subvariety" if you mean merely an open subset of a closed subset (or vice versa, since we are only dealing with points). Anyway, Chevalley's theorem tells us the image of any morphism of varieties is constructible, which in the case of affine varieties just means a union of finitely many principal open subsets of closed subsets.

@ZhenLin Thanks！But by Chevalley's theorem I can only prove that the image $\phi (X)$ is a constructible set. Is there any example showing that this image may not be an open subset of a closed subset?

I don't know. There probably is. If there were a simpler description I would expect it to mentioned in discussions of Chevalley's theorem.
